# Post matching query does not exist. When post exists in DB

Tags: django, mongodb

I'm creating a simple blog with a Django backend using MongoDB to store blog posts and their metadata.
Everything worked find when I was testing with a local mongodb instance, but when I switched to an atlas hosted database I started getting the following error.
[image: error]

The current Post model is
`

```
class Post(models.Model):

 _id = models.UUIDField(
    primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
 title = models.CharField(
    max_length=50, help_text='Post title. equivalent to obsidian file name')
  publish_date = models.DateField()
  last_edited = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
  content = models.TextField(blank=False)
  summary = models.TextField(blank=True)
  tags = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False)
  choices = [
    ('published', 'published'),
    ('draft', 'draft'),
    ('private', 'private')
  ]
  status = models.CharField(
    choices=choices, default='published', max_length=20, blank=False,)

  class Meta:
    pass

  def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('post', args=[self._id])

  def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

And the associated view

```
class PostDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Post

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PostDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        # context['post'].tags = context['post'].tags.split(',')
        context['post'].content = markdown.markdown(context['post'].content)

        return context
```

To debug I overrode the `get_object` method as follows:

```
      
      def get_object(self, *args, **kwargs):
          kwargs = self.kwargs
          kw_id = kwargs.get('pk')

          all_results = Post.objects.filter()
          print(all_results.first()._id == str(kw_id))
          result = Post.objects.get(_id=str(kw_id))
          print("result:", result)

          return result
```

assuming there is only one test post in the DB, `all_results = Post.objects.filter()` returns the post, but some of its element (e.g. `all_results.first().content` are `None` even though it is populated in the DB.
the main problem is that when trying to `filter` or `get` based on the value of the `_id` field no results are returned even though `print(all_results.first()._id == str(kw_id))` outputs `true`.
Any ideas as to what might be causing this, please?

Edit:
Since the posts are added from somewhere else (an obsidian plugin) I ran a test to compare the posts created from the admin page (which work properly) to those created by the plugin, and it seems that the id field which is created using typsscripts' `uuid.v4()` produce a mongodb string _id field whereas the posts created in the admin page end up with a `BinData` type. How can these be made to match ?

Comment: Can you share the view (with the "old" `get_object).

Comment: updated the post with the view and some new findings

Answer (score 0):

`all_results.first()._id` will return the _id and if you are comparing it with id that is not same with it will return `None`.

You can do:

```
def get_object(self, *args, **kwargs):
      kwargs = self.kwargs
      kw_id = kwargs.get('pk')

      all_results = Post.objects.filter(._id=str(kw_id))
      result = all_results.first()
      print("result:", result)
      return result
```

With that, you will have access to the first data from the DB.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up figuring it out.
The issue was the type compatibility of the _id field. On the typescript side I generate the `_id` using `mongoDB`'s `new ObjectId()`. On the Django side I convert the `_id` received as a string from `get_absolute_url()` to a `bson.objectid.ObjectId` class before doing the filtering.
I also changed the model to the following (switched to djongo fields)

```
from djongo import models

class Post(models.Model):

    _id = models.ObjectIdField(primary_key=True, editable=False)
    title = models.CharField(
        max_length=50, help_text='Post title. equivalent to obsidian file name')
    publish_date = models.DateField()
    last_edited = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    contents = models.TextField(blank=False)
    summary = models.TextField(blank=True)
    # tags = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False)
    tags = models.JSONField(max_length=20)
    choices = [
        ('published', 'published'),
        ('draft', 'draft'),
        ('private', 'private')
    ]
    status = models.CharField(
        choices=choices, default='published', max_length=20, blank=False,)

    objects = models.DjongoManager()

    class Meta:
        pass

    def get_absolute_url(self):

        return reverse('post', args=[self._id])

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Now the types are consistent everywhere and the queries are successful.